# VS 2010 c++ Express -- PERIODICALLY fopen function fails on ALL projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS 2010 C++ Express to develop win32 apps on a 64-bit PC running 64-bit Win 7.

Occasionally, when trying to run an app in debug, the fopen() function will return null values for all of the fields of FILE *fin.  What is interesting is that, when this problem occurs, it occurs in ALL of my VS 2010 C++ Express projects -- including those that previously have run properly in IDE
without any intervening changes to the source code or to project settings.

I.e., it is the IDE that appears to be misbehaving -- not my projects that suddenly decided in concert to malfunction and then fix themselves.

This problem has occurred twice before.  The problem persisted thru a series of the following actions:

(1)  Closing and reopening the IDE,

(2)  Restarting my PC,

(3)  Recreating the project,

(4)  Removing, redownloading and reinstalling VS 2010 C++ Express.

The problem was observed to be present after each of these actions.  Finally, a few days after it manifested the problem disappeared as mysteriously as it appeared.

I have visited the answered questions on StackOverflow that are relevant to this issue. None of these address this specific problem.

Has anyone else experienced this problem and had similar suspicions?

Also, can anyone recommend a good alternative (and free) C++ compiler other than something from Microsoft?

Comment: When `fopen` fails, you should print out the value of [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno), possibly using [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get a printable string describing the error. It might help giving you ideas as to what's happening.

Comment: My guess would be "Antivirus software"... It can certainly have this sort of effect, by being "daft".

Comment: You should also check if some other process is using way more CPU power than it should, or if some process eats up handles and/or memory. You could start checking this with the normal task-manager.

Comment: Your IDE has nothing to do with the functionality of `fopen`

Comment: @EdS. Visual Studio affects the OS choice of memory allocator, and it's very reasonable to assume that `fopen` allocates memory.

Comment: Thank you all for your posts, which I have copied to my "win32 Lore" directory for future reference.  
The problem has disappeared again, on its own, without any intervention on my part.  If and when it recurs, I will post a MCT&R example.

Comment: @MSalters: Visual studio is just an IDE, you're talking about MS's standard library implementation.

Comment: @EdS. : No, I am explicitly not. It definitely is Visual Studio, in particular its debugger.